# Creating a list based on the values from a dictionary which satisfy a condition

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I have this dictionary and I want to make a list with the Id .. If their hasCategory is True.

```
categories = [{'Id': 1350, 'hasCategory': True},
              {'Id': 113563, 'hasCategory': True},
              {'Id': 328422, 'hasCategory': False}]
```

In this example my result list should be this

```
list = [1350, 113563]
```

I am trying with the above code

```
list =[]    
for item in categories:
    if item.hasCategory is True:
        list.push(item.Id)
```

But when I am trying to run my application I am having an error

```
for item in categories
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python expects you to mark the end of `if` and `for` with `:`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Basic problems found in the code**

1. You actually need to use `:` to mark the end of `if` and `for` statements, like this
2. Don't use any of the built-in names as your variable names. In this case, `list`.
3. To get a value from the dictionary, you need to get it with `["key"]` method only. The dot notation will not work.

---

So your fixed code would look like this

```
result = []                      # list is a built-in name. Don't use that
for item in categories:          # : at the end
    if item["hasCategory"]:      # : at the end
        result.push(item["Id"])
```

Apart from that, the Pythonic way to check if a variable is Truthy, is just

```
if expression:
```

That is why we are not checking

```
if item["hasCategory"] == True:
```

or

```
if item["hasCategory"] is True:    # Never use `is` to compare values
```

Quoting [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Style Guide for Python Code,

> Don't compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`.
>
> ```
> Yes:   if greeting:
> No:    if greeting == True:
> Worse: if greeting is True:
> ```

---

The best way to solve this problem is to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a filtering condition, like this

```
>>> [item["Id"] for item in categories if item["hasCategory"]]
[1350, 113563]
```

It will just create a new list, based on your old iterable, in this case `categories`.

Comment: but your last list comprehension returns `1350` if the input is `[{ 'Id': 1350, 'hasCategory': 'm'}]`. Op wants the value should be `True` not any other values i think.

Comment: Thank you my friend for all the useful information.. Greetings from Greece.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the implication both of the name of the key `hasCategory` and the example given is that it is being used to store a boolean. The answer given fits that interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use list_comprehension here.

```
>>> categories=   [{ 'Id': 1350, 'hasCategory': True},
               { 'Id': 113563, 'hasCategory': True},
               { 'Id': 328422, 'hasCategory': False}]
>>> [i['Id'] for i in categories if i['hasCategory'] == True]
[1350, 113563]
```

Comment: thank you for the concern my friend.. I learnt list_comprehension from you :)

Answer (score 0):

you should have ":" after your loop:

```
for item in categories:
```